# Clearcase to Subversion Migration

Tags: clearcase

How to migrate the datas from clearcase to subversion? I have a vob of size 30 GB and i should not miss any datas during the migration? Please provide me a valid information to do this process?

Answer (score 1):

I was once watching as this discussion unfolded once, and honestly, it's not an easy process on paper. The only tool explicitly for migration that I've found is [Polarion Software's Importer for SVN](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer.php). There are other connectors and bridges, both free and commercial, that you might be able to use for migration as well.

But if the decision to do this hasn't been set in stone yet, you might want to know what you are getting into. The two best articles that I still have bookmarked are [a blog post from CollabNet](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2007/04/migration_from_.html) and [a question on StackOverflow about migration strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542479/what-is-the-best-strategy-when-migrating-from-clearcase-to-svn) - if you search around, you can probably find blogs and posts by people who have made the leap to see what worked for them, I just don't have any bookmarked or easily accessible. The SO question also linked to another [question that mentioned specific strategies for actually performing the migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494/recommendation-on-tools-to-migrate-from-clearcase-to-svn) - the accepted answer was the Polarion tool, but other options include custom scripts.